# Getting comma in the joined array with string

Tags: javascript

I don't know why I have a comma when I use `join` method. Can anyone explain?

```js
function maskify(cc) {
  var a = cc.slice(cc.length - 4, cc.length);
  var b = cc.slice(0, cc.length - 4);
  b = b.split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = "#";

  }
  b.join("#");
  console.log(b + a);
}

maskify("sadasdasdasdasdasd");
// result : #,#,#,#,#,dasd
```

Comment: yes i mean comma

Comment: you are doing `b.join(""#");` but not storing it anywere

Answer (score 2):

`Join()` is the method of array which allows to join its element as string and returns. `Join()` takes one argument which is separator, the default value is ",". You need to specify empty string if you want to join without any separator. For reference refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=control).

For your code, you are joining but not storing, and again converting it to string by using + operator with variable `a`

```js
    function maskify(cc) {
      var a = cc.slice(cc.length - 4, cc.length);
      var b = cc.slice(0, cc.length - 4);
      b = b.split("");
      for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i] = "#";
    
      }
      var output=b.join("#");
      console.log(output + a);
    }
    
    maskify("sadasdasdasdasdasd");
    // result : #,#,#,#,#,dasd
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `split` on `b`, `b` is an array of individual characters. When logging `b + a`, since `b` is an array and `a` a string, `+` will act as string concatenation operator. `b` is converted to string using `toString()` implicitly. [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString?v=control#Description) on array returns string of array elements joined by `,`. So, you're getting comma in the final output.

Simple solution to solve this problem is to explicitly `join` the array elements before concatenating.

```js
function maskify(cc) {
  var a = cc.slice(cc.length - 4, cc.length);
  var b = cc.slice(0, cc.length - 4);
  b = b.split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = "#";

  }
  b.join("#");
  console.log(b.join('') + a);
}

maskify("sadasdasdasdasdasd");
```

Another way to achieve same results is using [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

```js
var str = 'sadasdasdasdasdasd';

var maskedStr = '#'.repeat(str.length -4) + str.slice(-4);
console.log(maskedStr);
```

Note that this is supported in latest browsers/environments only. Check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Browser_compatibility), if not supported use [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Polyfill).

Answer (score 1):

It's because when concatinating an array and a string, the array is implicitly converted into a string.

```
var array = [...];
array + "";
```

is the same as:

```
array.toString() + "";
```

and `[4, 5].toString()` is `"4,5"` (add a `,` by default).

**Why?**

Because, when this line is reached:

```
console.log(b + a);
```

`a` will be a string because it was cut from the string `cc`. And `b` is an array because it is the result of the split, and `b.join` don't change `b` to a string, it just return a string that you don't use and leaves `b` intact (so `b` remains an array).

**Fix:**

Use the result of `b.join` not `b`:

```
console.log(b.join("#") + a);
```

or:

```
b = b.join("#");
console.log(b + a);
```

Answer (score 0):

i add

```
var c = b.concat(a);
c.join("");
```

It's working . Thanks u so much :D

Comment: Please indicate the correct answer and thank the person who posted it by upvoting and/or accepting that answer, not by posting an answer that's actually a comment.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more information.